Use paths in YAML of Quarto
I am creating multiple dashboards in one folder. Imagine we have a subfolder with logos of these dashboards. I would like to mention these logos with a relative path in the YAML header of each document. It doesn't work so I tried this, How to use here() for paths to css, before_body and after_body?. Unfortunately this doesn't work. Here I created some reproducible code:
---
title: "Palmer Penguins"
author: "Quinten"
format: 
  dashboard:
    embed-resources: true
logo: !expr here::here("logos/penguins.png")
theme: 
  - zephyr
---

```{r}
# import packages
library(tidyverse)
library(crosstalk)
library(DT)
library(plotly)
library(gt)
library(palmerpenguins)

# import data
penguins <- palmerpenguins::penguins

# Crosstalk dataset
shared_penguins <- SharedData$new(penguins)

# Set theme
theme_set(theme_minimal())
```

# {.sidebar}

This is a simple static dashboard to show what is possible with the newest version of [Quarto v1.4](https://quarto.org/docs/blog/posts/2024-01-24-1.4-release/). To make it a bit interactive we use the [crosstalk](https://github.com/rstudio/crosstalk) package and [plotly](https://plotly.com/r/).

***

In this dashboard we visualize the [palmerpenguins](https://allisonhorst.github.io/palmerpenguins/) dataset. In the table below is some basic information about the data:

| Specie       |  Count             |
|--------------|---------------------|
| **Adelie**     | `{r} nrow(subset(penguins, species == "Adelie"))`  |
| **Gentoo**   | `{r} nrow(subset(penguins, species == "Gentoo"))`   |
| **Chinstrap**  | `{r} nrow(subset(penguins, species == "Chinstrap"))` |

```{r}
filter_checkbox("sex", "Sex", shared_penguins, ~sex)
```

***

# Analysis

## Row {height=40%}

### Column {width=80%}

```{r}
#| title: "Slider options"
slider_width = 800
htmltools::div(
    id = "sliderdiv", 
    filter_slider("bill_length_mm", "bill length", shared_penguins, ~bill_length_mm, width = slider_width),
    filter_slider("bill_depth_mm", "bill depth", shared_penguins, ~bill_depth_mm, width = slider_width),
    filter_slider("flipper_length_mm", "flipper length", shared_penguins, ~flipper_length_mm, width = slider_width),
    filter_slider("body_mass_g", "body mass", shared_penguins, ~body_mass_g, width = slider_width)
)
```

### Column {width=20%}

```{r}
#| content: valuebox
#| title: "Number of penguins"
list(
  icon = "tencent-qq",
  color = "primary",
  value = nrow(penguins)
)
```

## Row {height=60%}

```{r}
#| title: "Flipper length vs body mass"
p <- ggplot(shared_penguins, aes(x = flipper_length_mm, y = body_mass_g, color = species, shape = species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkorange","darkorchid","cyan4")) 

ggplotly(p)
```

```{r}
#| title: "bill length by species"
p <- ggplot(data = penguins, aes(x = species, y = bill_length_mm)) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = species),
              width = 0.1, 
              alpha = 0.7,
              show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkorange","darkorchid","cyan4"))
ggplotly(p)
```

Output:

As you can see the logo isn't shown in the top left. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to use relative paths in the yaml of Quarto?

Using ‘here’ inside a Quarto/RMarkdown document doesn’t really make sense: the way the renderer is works, the working directory is fixed to the document, so a regular relative path is sufficient. At best, putting here::here() around it will do nothing. At worst, it can break things.

Maybe you found the solution already, if not:
The trick is to locate the logo files in a folder named "www"
and your YAML should look like that
---
title: "Palmer Penguins"
author: "Quinten"
format:
  dashboard:
    embed-resources: true
logo: www/penguins.png
theme:
  - zephyr
---

Then you will get a quarto dashboard with logo:

